# cannot trust development https self-signed certificate in ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: ssl, https, .net-core, ubuntu-18.04, self-signed

I created a rest api project and I'm tring to access the https endpoint using curl like this:

```sh
$ dotnet new angular

$ curl -I -X GET 'https://localhost:5001/api/SampleData/WeatherForecasts'
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I googled around and these are the steps I took to extract the certificate from dotnet and add it to my repository of trusted CA certificates:

This is what I tried to do to add the certificate

```sh
# export netcore development certificate
$ dotnet dev-certs https -ep ~/tmp/localhost.pfx -p somepassword

# convert it to crt
$ openssl pkcs12 -in ~/tmp/localhost.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out ~/tmp/localhost.crt

# copy to a folder in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ 
$ cd /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
$ sudo mkdir dotnet_devel
$ sudo chmod -R 755 dotnet_devel
$ mkdir dotnet_devel
$ cd dotnet_devel
$ sudo cp ~/tmp/localhost.crt .
$ sudo chmod -R 644 localhost.crt

# update CA trusted certificates repository
$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

Adding debian:localhost.pem
done.
done.
```

I also tried setting the CURL_CA_BUNDLE env var like this:

```sh
$ export CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/dotnet_devel/localhost.crt
```

I keep getting the same curl error, more over, firefox and chrome tells me the connection is not secure

Additional info:

```
$ dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.203
 Commit:    e5bab63eca

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  18.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64

$ curl --version
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4 libpsl/0.19.1 (+libidn2/2.0.4) nghttp2/1.30.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2018-01-24
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy PSL
```

```sh
$ openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/dotnet_devel/localhost.crt -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 7146369397181644036 (0x632d011a88bbfd04)
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = localhost
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 22 19:40:53 2018 GMT
            Not After : Oct 22 19:40:53 2019 GMT
        Subject: CN = localhost
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
    [...]
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: critical
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: critical
                DNS:localhost
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1: 
                ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    [...]
```

References:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/645818/how-to-install-certificates-for-command-line/649463#649463

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/7246#issue-406461992

https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: Could you include the output of `openssl x509 -in /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/dotnet_devel/localhost.crt -text -noout` ? Firefox and Chrome operate with their own trust stores, so trust needs to be configured individually for both browsers

Comment: sure, there it goes

Comment: Certificate validation is more than whether you have added it to your certificate store. Validation means that the check can validate the entire certificate chain back to the original issuer. That will not work for a self-signed certificate. There is no certificate chain. While self-signed certificates were useful 10 years ago to enable ssl, today they are more trouble than they are worth since you must create an exception with every application that allows their use. Best to simply use `certbot` and get a free valid certificate to use from EFF for the server.

Comment: good tip, can I use certbot to create a certificate for my localhost? any link that my help me get started with it?

Answer (score -2):

```
services.AddScoped(s =>
                {
                    // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
                    var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
                    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (message, xcert, chain, errors) => true;
                    return new HttpClient(handler)
                    {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                    };
                });
```

Comment: When answering an old question, your answer would be much more useful to other StackOverflow users if you included some context to explain how your answer helps. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).